# how to use this in terminal:

Tags: c, terminal

I got a moddified ls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char command[50];
    strcpy(command,"/bin/ls ");
    gid_t egid = getegid();
    setregid(egid, egid);
    if(argc > 1) {
        if(strlen(argv[1]) > 40) {
            printf("The command you have given is too long, try again.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        strcat(command,argv[1]);
        system(command);
    }else{
        printf("This is a special NSA-modified 'ls' program. See 'man ls' for further details on how to use it.\n");
        printf("USAGE: %s [flags & files]\n",argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i have to execute a program called get-code but i don't have the privileges to execute it without the ls(the modified ls is in the same directory as the get-code program), so how can i fool the system() to execute the get-code using the modified ls?

Comment: Hint: `system` always passes its string to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: are you asking how you can use this program to run arbitrary code? You'll have to pick an argv[1] such that `command` will execute something else after the ls.

Comment: the code above is the code for the modified ls program that will run with root privileges, however i dont have the privileges to run the get-code program which i need to run... but i dont know how to use this ls program to execute the get-code program... can you help pls i have been busy with this for a week now

Comment: Is this for a class? Why not ask your professor? This is a relatively simple problem and you should let your professor know if you are struggling with it.

Comment: the professor is not responding because it is a 'hacking' assignment which is done on linux, the web hack course is already competed and wa s the best of class with that, but the rest is better in this than me(could be because they are from a higher class) i am 17 years old and dutch and i do struggle a lot now

Comment: The key is this line: `strcat(command,argv[1]);` How can you make it so `command` does more than just ls?

Comment: the previous course was with a moddified find program, i used ./find -exec /courses/InetSec1/challenge4/get-code {} \; and that worked but the ls is really diffecult and the teacher who can respond doesn't know how to do it(best ICT teacher ever)

Comment: that is what the teacher indeed said but i am 17 and really new to this and dont know what i should do thats why i posted this question online........

Comment: you didn't answer my question, how can you execute multiple commands on one line in a shell?

Comment: i dont know that.... or is it | ? with piping(i heard about that but i dont know how to use it) we just got a server to hack and they said well try to hack thats everything with only the knowledge of HTML and Css

Comment: If you don't know something, google it. It's essential if you are trying to learn something tech related. To execute multiple commands on the same line, you can separate them with the `;` character. So `echo "hello"; echo "world"` will have the shell execute both of those commands, one after the other. Knowing that, how can you make `system(command);` execute `get-code` after `ls`?

Comment: http://puu.sh/7qJwP.png i already tried but it didnt work

Comment: the first if denies me from doing it

Comment: You are very close. Remember, `command` ALREADY contains `/bin/ls`, you don't have to add that. Look back at the code: `strcpy(command,"/bin/ls ");`. You are appending to that.

Comment: :D thanks for the amazing help! puu.sh/7qJSB.png it did work! i got my special code for excercize 6 i hope it is something else this time!

Comment: can i upvote you or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is this line: `strcat(command,argv[1]);` How can you make it so command does more than just ls?

To execute multiple commands on the same line, you can separate them with the `;` character. So `echo "hello"; echo "world"` will have the shell execute both of those commands, one after the other. Knowing that, how can you make `system(command);` execute `get-code` after `ls`?